# How can I extract this text from this HTML Container with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I used this code:
`messages_blocks = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "x1fqp7bg")`
to get all containers containing different information I need. Here is how the containers look like:

```
<div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j xuk3077 x78zum5 x1q0g3np x1nhvcw1 x1jchvi3 xlxfd2w x1gslohp x126k92a"><div class="x1rg5ohu x67bb7w"><img class="x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x14yjl9h xudhj91 x18nykt9 xww2gxu x1ypdohk x1lliihq img" alt="Manuel Marchie" src="https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.30497-1/84628273_176159830277856_972693363922829312_n.jpg?stp=c59.0.200.200a_dst-jpg_p200x200&amp;_nc_cat=1&amp;ccb=1-7&amp;_nc_sid=12b3be&amp;_nc_ohc=O7CR_V32jMkAX-d2qoC&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-vie1-1.xx&amp;oh=00_AfCWMM9EsteVjxrm3mKJ4Qo-tRDbpMOHRYyY53yuob1TWQ&amp;oe=64D74E19" width="32" height="32"></div><div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x6s0dn4 x78zum5 x1q0g3np x193iq5w xh8yej3"><div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x1cy8zhl x78zum5 xdl72j9 xdt5ytf x1c4vz4f x2lah0s x16fdfms x161msgk x1s9ed0f x1eapu41 x1r944mn xet2fuk"><div class="x1rg5ohu x67bb7w"><div class="x1y1aw1k xn6708d xwib8y2 x1ye3gou x13faqbe x1eied1y xca6lcq x1pdtjp8 xpctjk2 xogfrqt x1slwz57 xt0e3qv"><span><span>yeah yeah yeah</span></span></div></div></div><div class=""></div></div> <img alt="Gesehen von Manuel Marchie – 14:41" class="x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x14yjl9h xudhj91 x18nykt9 xww2gxu xjpr12u x10l6tqk xlftelb img" title="Gesehen von Manuel Marchie – 14:41" src="https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.30497-1/84628273_176159830277856_972693363922829312_n.jpg?stp=c59.0.200.200a_dst-jpg_p200x200&amp;_nc_cat=1&amp;ccb=1-7&amp;_nc_sid=12b3be&amp;_nc_ohc=O7CR_V32jMkAX-d2qoC&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-vie1-1.xx&amp;oh=00_AfCWMM9EsteVjxrm3mKJ4Qo-tRDbpMOHRYyY53yuob1TWQ&amp;oe=64D74E19" width="15" height="15"> </div><div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x78zum5 x1nhvcw1"></div>
```

I want to extract the text "yeah yeah yeah" or whatever text is inside this container so I tried this:

```
messages : list[str] = []
for message_block in message_blocks:
    messages.append(message_block.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "(don't now what comes here)"))
```

I tried several class names, but nothing worked.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: messages: List[str] = []
for message_block in message_blocks:
    try:
        span_element = message_block.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span")
        text = span_element.text
        messages.append(text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        messages.append("")

Comment: You need to extract the text within `<span>` with respect to **Manuel Marchie** or **Gesehen von Manuel Marchie – 14:41**